# iptables - default action at the end of user-defined chain

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall

I'm reading iptables' man page at https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables, and I've got a question regarding the use of user-defined chains:

In the **Targets** section, it says

> If the end of a built-in chain is reached or a rule in a built-in chain with target RETURN is matched, the target specified by the chain policy determines the fate of the packet.

And underneath in the **Options** section, it also says

> Only built-in (non-user-defined) chains can have policies, and neither built-in nor user-defined chains can be policy targets.

So my question is, what happens when a packet goes into a user-defined chain, and reaches the end without matching **any** of the rules? In other words, what is the **default action** of a user-defined chain?

---

The reason I'm asking is I'm wondering if it's necessary to add a catch-all rule to the end of every user-defined chain. Something like

```
iptables -A MY-CHAIN -j RETURN
```

Or is this the default behavior? Or something else?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If none of the rules in a user-defined chain match, the default behavior is effectively `RETURN`: processing will continue at the next rule in the parent chain.

> When a packet matches a rule whose target is a user-defined chain, the packet begins traversing the rules in that user-defined chain. If that chain doesn't decide the fate of the packet, then once traversal on that chain has finished, traversal resumes on the next rule in the current chain.

(from the [Linux 2.4 Packet Filtering HOWTO](https://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/packet-filtering-HOWTO-7.html#ss7.4))

Comment: Thank you very much, and +1. Could you elaborate a bit further: Does this behavior depend on whether the custom chain has been reached via `--jump` or via `--goto`, as the bevior of `-j RETURN` does? Probably this is the case, but I couldn't find this clearly stated anywhere yet.

Comment: The `iptables` man page describes the behavior of the `--goto` option: *Unlike the --jump option return will not continue processing in this chain but instead in the chain that called us via --jump.* I haven't personally verified this behavior, but that should be reasonably easy.

Comment: Thanks again. I have verified the behavior in the meantime; it is as expected. Furthermore, it is just logical that a no-matching chain behaves as if `-j RETURN` was at the end, which just means different behavior depending on the way that chain has been activated.